# On the Fundamental theorem of Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

A proof from An Introduction to Optimization By Edwin Chong and Zak

Theorem 15.1 Fundamental Theorem of LPP. Consider a linear program in standard
form.

1. If there exists a feasible solution, then there exists a basic feasible solution;
2. If there exists an optimal feasible solution, then there exists an optimal basic
   feasible solution.

   Proof. We first prove part 1. Suppose that $x = [x_1,..., x_n]^T$ is a feasible solution
   and it has $p$ positive components. Without loss of generality, we can assume that the
   first $p$ components are positive, whereas the remaining components are zero. Then,
   in terms of the columns of $A = [a_1,..., a_p, . . . , a_n]$ this solution satisfies

   $x_1a_1+...x_pa_p=b$.

There are now two cases to consider.

Case 1: If $a_1, a_2,..., a_p$ are linearly independent, then $p \leq m$. If $p = m$, then
the solution $x$ is basic and the proof is completed. If, on the other hand, $p < m$,
then, since $rank A = m$, we can find $m—p$ columns of A from the remaining $n — p$ columns so that the resulting set of m columns forms a basis. Hence, the solution $x$
is a (degenerate) basic feasible solution corresponding to the above basis.

Case 2: Assume that $a_1, a_2,..., a_p$ are linearly dependent. Then, there exist
numbers $y_i, i = 1, . . . , p $ not all zero, such that $y_1a_1+..y_pa_p=0$

We can assume that there exists at least one $y_i$ that is positive, for if all the $y_i$ are
nonpositive, we can multiply the above equation by $-1$. Multiply the above equation
by a scalar $\epsilon$ and subtract the resulting equation from $x_1a_1+...x_pa_p=b$
to obtain $(x_1-\epsilon y_1)a_1+....+(x_p-\epsilon y_p)a_p=b$

Let $y=[y_1,..y_p,0,..0]^T$.then Then, for any $\epsilon$

we can write $A[x-\epsilon y]=b$

Let $\epsilon$ = min{$xi/yi : i = 1,..., p, yi > 0$}. Then, the first $p$ components o f $x — \epsilon y$
are nonnegative, and at least one of these components is zero. We then have a feasible
solution with at most $p — 1$ positive components. We can repeat this process until we
get linearly independent columns of A, after which we are back to Case 1. Therefore,
part 1 is proved.

We now prove part 2. Suppose that $x = [ x_1 , . . . , x_n]^T$ is an optimal feasible
solution, and only the first $p$ variables are nonzero. Then, we have two cases to
consider. The first case (Case 1) is exactly the same as in part 1. The second
case (Case 2) follows the same arguments as in part 1, but in addition we must
show that $x — \epsilon y$ is optimal for any $\epsilon$. We do this by showing that $c^Ty = 0$.
To this end, assume $c^Ty \neq 0$. Note that for $\epsilon$ of sufficiently small magnitude
($|\epsilon|$ $ \leq$ min{$|\frac{x_i}{y_i}| : i = 1,... ,p, y_i > 0$}), the vector$x — \epsilon y$ is feasible. We
can choose $\epsilon$ such that $c^Tx> c^Tx — \epsilon c^Ty =c^T(x-\epsilon y)$. This contradicts the
optimality of x . We can now use the procedure from part 1 to obtain an optimal basic
feasible solution from a given optimal feasible solution.

My question is for second part, how they defined the range for $\epsilon$ that $|\epsilon|$ $ \leq$ min{$|\frac{x_i}{y_i}| : i = 1,... ,p, y_i > 0$}.